# How to allocate and de-allocate memory for CFFI structure

Tags: c++, python-2.7, python-cffi

I have structure in C++ as below

```
typedef struct user
{
    unsigned long           id;
    char                   *name;
    struct1                 type;
    int                     Period;
    char                   *altername;
    char                   *description;
    struct2                 state;
    struct3                *userDetails;
} CUser;

typedef struct _CDeltaUser
{
    CUser                  *deltaUser;
    struct3                *deletedUserDetails;
    struct3                *changedUserValues;
} CDeltaUser;
```

I am trying to create a object for this structure through CFFI and assign the values for the members and pass the created object to a API in C++.

```
deltaUser = ffi.new("CDeltaUser*")

deltaUser.deltaUser = ffi.new("CUser*") 

deltaUser.deltaUser.id=4
```

Now when i try to pass this deltaUser to an API in C++ through the dll loaded using ffi.dlopen **ApiName(par1,par2,deltaUser,par4)** python crashes at this point. crash occurs both in windows and Linux.

What is wrong with this code ? I am using python2.7 and cffi 1.5.2

on traceback gives the following log. Found that value is optimised

in ffi_call (cif=0x7ffff1189260, fn=0x7ffff0488faa , rvalue=0x7ffff118e098, avalue=0x7ffff118e078) at src/x86/ffi64.c:484 in cdata_call (cd=0x7ffff118c0d0, args=0x7ffff7ee4310, kwds=) at c/_cffi_backend.c:2637 in PyObject_Call (func=0x7ffff118c0d0, arg=, kw=) at Objects/abstract.c:2529 in do_call (f=, throwflag=) at Python/ceval.c:4239 call_function (f=, throwflag=) at Python/ceval.c:4044

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its a c++ code. updated the question.

Comment: Any stacktrace from a coredump available?

Comment: in ffi_call (cif=0x7ffff1189260, fn=0x7ffff0488faa <userchangeinfo(int, int, void*, CfgErrorCode*)>, rvalue=0x7ffff118e098, avalue=0x7ffff118e078) at src/x86/ffi64.c:484
in cdata_call (cd=0x7ffff118c0d0, args=0x7ffff7ee4310, kwds=<value optimized out>) at c/_cffi_backend.c:2637
in PyObject_Call (func=0x7ffff118c0d0, arg=<value optimized out>, kw=<value optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2529
in do_call (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4239
call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4044

Comment: Wow, can you modify your question to include it :-)